# OnApplicationPause works with delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to save data via firebase SetValueAsync function, when app in background using OnApplicationPause

```
 void OnApplicationPause (bool pauseStatus) {
    if (pauseStatus) {
        databaseReference.Child ("UsersOnline").Child (id).SetValueAsync (false);
        BackToMenu ();
    }
}
```

But the problem starts when app running more than 3-4 minutes, then OnApplicationPause works with some sort of delay. If user terminates app using task manager in that time, it will not save anything.
P.S. everything works fine in the editor, issue appear only on phones.

Comment: I'ld suspect that rather `SetValueAsync (false);` has some delay .. since it is async, if the app is close forced maybe it doesn't reach the actual transmition

Comment: I'm also thinked about that, but looks like firebase have only async functions to save data in unity